# Programmatically verify if a UDP port is bound in C/C++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

Without attempting to bind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
int getsockname(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
   socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

Comment: ...interpreting the question as "I think I bound a UDP socket, but I'm not sure if I did", then yes.  (It's not the first interpretation I came to, but unless OP speaks up otherwise, it seems valid to me.)

Comment: According to [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockname.html), "If the socket has not been bound to a local name, the value stored in the object pointed to by *address* is unspecified." Thus, there is no guarantee that any meaningful information will be present in `address` if the socket is unbound, and this doesn't answer the question.